# Trying to find a movie about students venturing underground to find lost necklace and meeting a monster

Tags: story-identification

I watched this when I was in elementary school (maybe in 2003), and couldn't sleep well for days. I would really like to know the name of the movie. From what I remember:
In the beginning a boy played around with a girl's necklace and it accidentally fell into the sewage system. Then they decided to go into the sewage system to search for it, leading them to an underground world where a monster lived. The monster ate or killed humans and walked around an elevator (not sure about this part). There was a scene when the monster cannot touch the kids because they circled themselves with some magical item. The teenagers tried to find the way out. 
Hope someone has seen this movie~~

Comment: Some of the elements remind me of Stephen King's It.

Comment: Same film https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3534yi/tomt_film_three_kids_follow_a_droppedlost/ - But the OP there thinks it's three kids, not one.

Comment: Someone else looking for the same film; https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141123191938AAVBDgy ?

Comment: You're looking for [Demon in the Bottle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116074/combined) from 1996. Everything you've mentioned is there. You can see a (dubbed) clip from it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYDieIO76gY). Not putting it up as an answer as it was already answered in this [old M&TV thread](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/movie-about-kids-entering-an-old-mansion-and-finding-a-bottle-lamp).

Comment: Aw man... and here I was watching through the movie to see if I could find matches. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above, it's likely that you're looking for *[Demon in the Bottle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116074/)* (1996). It features four teenagers who accidentally release a demon from its bottle. He drops the necklace around the 13 minute mark after retrieving it from a bully.

Dubbed full version: